# use of "response" in fetching tweets from search API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and javascript. here i have a code which fetches tweets using twitter;s search api. Can yo please tell me why are we passing the argument "response" to the function after .done()? How is this working ?

```
 $('#input').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
           var hashtag = $(this).find('input[name="hashtag"]').val();
            var twitterapi = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?";
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: twitterapi,
              data: {
                "q": hashtag,
                "rpp": 1000
              },
              dataType: 'jsonp'
            }).done(function (response) {
              var results = response.results;
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $("#tweet").append("<p class='tweet'>" +
                  "<span class='username'>" +
                  results[i].from_user +
                  "</span> <span class='tweet_content'> " +
                  results[i].text + "</span></p>");
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In done function you add a function parameter also known as callback function. 
.done is asynchronous call, once call is received by twitter server the result
is passed in the callback (function inside .done()). The response data is returned
in response variable.

Comment: so the "response" word represents the data from twitter ? Can i change to anything? or it has to be response only ?

Comment: You cannot change anything about response, repsonse contains data from twitter. Oh ya you can name it anything you want like 'twitterresponse' etc.